# Problem with LED strips

Tags: led-strip

I am using a 30V 50A power supply (KXN-3050D) as an external power source.  I have an led strip with 120 LEDs.

The problem is that when I drive 50 LEDs (in full brightness and white,) the power supply provides 1A but when I want to drive more than 50 LEDs, my power supply still provides 1A and the LEDs after 50 turn yellow.I'm going to share the circuit I set up below.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: https://blog.yakupulutas.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/arduino_usb_and_extrenal_power_ws2812.jpg]

Comment: What is the capabilities of your power supply? What is the current draw of the LED strip?

Comment: That power supply has a current control set of knobs. Do you have the current set down at 1A?

Comment: My power supply normally provides up to 50 amps. 50 LEDs draw 1A and glow smoothly.But when I turn on 70 LEDs, it draws 1A again and after 50 LEDs turn yellow.

Comment: If you power the LED strip from the other end, does the behavior change sides (LEDs close to power are white)? And what if you power it from both ends?

Comment: Are you powering the arduino through the Vin? If so the current will be limited by the linear regulator and fuses.

Comment: It's probably the voltage drop within your LED strip causing problems. If you feed the power to the center of a strip of 70 LEDs you will likely be ok.

Comment: Does the CC LED glow? If so then the supply enters overcurrent (set to 1A via Current knob). You can increase the limit by turning the Current knob clockwise.

Comment: I agree with @Jack Creasey, feed the 5V into the middle and ends of the LED strip.

Comment: You must not cascade 5m LEDstrips without expecting dim results. Ensure power cable to each strip can support low V/I drop.  Measure V at intervals to determine best way to supply voltage

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the suggestions and for the solution!Especially @JackCreasey,
The problem is definitely the voltage drop. I've re-fed about every 50 LEDs, and my problem is solved.

Comment: @WesleyLee I would also like to ask you another question that stuck in my mind.What's the difference between feeding the Arduino with Vin or + 5V USB?

Comment: Vin goes through the regulator, AFAIK the USB input is fused (so also not gonna allow much more than 500mA~1A to pass). You'd have to plug +5V into the +5V directly. (DO NOT plug anything other than 5V at the 5V pin)

Comment: Look into the schematic of your arduino and the path the current takes. Actually, don't run >1A through the Arduino.

Comment: 1) If I regulate the 24V battery and obtain 5V, can I supply the USB input?
2) If I feed Arduino like this, will there be any current limitation?

Answer (score 2):

The power wires (tracks) on the LED strip have too much resistance to support that many LEDs. You should run extra power wires alongside the LED strip, and connect them at each end of each strip.

The affected LEDs appear yellow because the blue component of each LED needs a higher voltage to turn on. Taking away blue from white gives yellow.